# using fopen('php://output', 'w') in joomla is creating <!-- START: SRC_COMPONENT --> in first line

Tags: php, joomla, export-to-csv

Title says it really. Here is the relevant part:

```
    $cols = array('One','Two','Three');
    $items = $db->setQuery($this->getListQuery())->loadAssocList();
    $csv = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($csv, $cols);
```

This outputs a file with all perfect except the first and last line have

```
    <!-- START: SRC_COMPONENT --> and <!-- END: SRC_COMPONENT -->
```

Anyone know where this comes from?
Thanks

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($cols)`? php doesn't randomly add text by itself.

Comment: I checked $cols and it's just an array as expected. I figure I'm doing something to cause Joomla to add it. I just don't know what. So I added ob_end_clean before the fputcsv call and it is clearing it. Thanks